# mongo Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In the mongodb offical documentation, it says:

> For example, the collection data has the following index:
>
> `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }`
>
> The following operations can use the index to get the sort order:
>
> Example
>
> `db.data.find( { a: 5 } ).sort( { b: 1, c: 1 } )`
>
> `db.data.find( { b: 3, a: 4 } ).sort( { c: 1 } )`
>
> `db.data.find( { a: 5, b: { $lt: 3} } ).sort( { b: 1 } )`

I do not understand the second example, why query `{b: 5, a: 4}` with sort `{c: 1}` can use the index `{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1}`.

Here is [offical documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

Comment: Because you are actually specifying `"a"` and `"b"` which **do in fact prefix the index**. I think you are basically being confused thinking that since you ordered the keys in the query as `"b"` and then `"a"` that this means it's different, but it it not. If instead your query was `{ "c": 4, "b": 3 }` or `{ "b": 3, "c": 4 }` **then** you are not able to use the index because the compound starts with **"a"**. The order of keys in the **query** does not matter. It's only the "keys in the index" that matter.

Comment: Also to add what Neil has mentioned, to MongoDB query planner, `db.collection.find({b:5, a:4})` is identical to `db.collection.find({a:4, b:5})`. That is, the order of the keys in what is essentially an `$and` query does not matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB : Indexes order and query order must match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245737/mongodb-indexes-order-and-query-order-must-match)